# can't firebase login in Cloud 9

Tags: cloud9-ide, firebase-tools, cloud9

Installed firebase-tools in Cloud 9. To set it up, tried `firebase login` but can't get the auth for the cli. After clicking on the authentication link that's provided, the redirect url looks for the localhost which obviously can't be reached.

Answer on [cloud9](https://community.c9.io/t/terminal-waiting-for-authenication/5789) support makes sense but did everything that's been told there and still can't make it work. The authentication link itself already has localhost to redirect to and the port is by default 9005 in the link - manually changing it to c9 workspace preview url or port number returns "redirect url mismatched" from Google.

Anybody else tried firebase-tools in Cloud 9 and made this work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From [Michael Bleigh's answer on the firebase-talk group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/XDge1RkP5cs):

> Try running

```
firebase login --no-localhost
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It generated an authorization code that I had to paste in the console.