# I'm unable to login in firebase using "firebase login"

Tags: authentication, firebase, firebase-tools

I installed node.js and downloaded firebase tools. After that when I enter "firebase login" in the cmd, nothing prompts up. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you done `firebase init` before ?

Comment: Tried that. even that's not working. But I think login is to be done before init.

Answer (score 1):

Already answered here: [can't firebase login in Cloud 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528535/cant-firebase-login-in-cloud-9)

In short use: `firebase login --no-localhost`
Copy and paste the code using ctrl+c on windows or corresponding command on mac